# 16 to 18 Upgrade Stuck - upstart, systemd issues

Tags: upgrade, systemd, upstart

Hi I might need a bit of help with upgrading Ubuntu on virtual server, it seems it upgraded to 18 but there are some dependancies errors and none of the restart commands are found in terminal.

"Apt-get -f install" doesn't help and just gives same error about unmet dependancies.

Could auto cleaning dependancies delete some stuff that is used by other programs? That stops me from trying it.

I'm also worried if Ubuntu fails to start I will have to delete it and lose data.

Here are some details as requested:

**PPA**

I don't think there are any but not sure how I can check, maybe files you requested will show, they are below.

**Ubuntu version**: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-170-generic x86_64)

**sudo apt update**

```
Hit:1 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                   
Hit:3 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                 
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                    
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.                                          
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IE:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
keys on reference is experimental at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 264.
keys on reference is experimental at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 359.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1565 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

**sudo apt upgrade**
(shows the error I was talking about which appears in various cases/commands)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-setup : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5) but 1.178ubuntu2.9 is installed
 console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5) but 1.178ubuntu2.9 is installed
 indicator-datetime : Depends: systemd or
                               systemd-shim but it is not installable
                      Recommends: unity-control-center (>= 14.04.3) but it is not installed or
                                  ubuntu-system-settings but it is not installable
                      Recommends: ubuntu-touch-sounds but it is not installed
 indicator-session : Depends: systemd-services
                     Recommends: unity-control-center-signon but it is not installable or
                                 gnome-control-center-signon but it is not installable
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.16) but 0.130ubuntu3.9 is installed
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.24) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.24) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.33)
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27)
 systemd-sysv : PreDepends: systemd
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell but it is not installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator but it is not installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it is not installed
                  Depends: gstreamer1.0-packagekit but it is not installed
                  Depends: libu2f-udev but it is not installed
                  Depends: spice-vdagent but it is not installed
                  Recommends: dirmngr
                  Recommends: fonts-indic but it is not installed
                  Recommends: fonts-noto-cjk but it is not installed
                  Recommends: fonts-noto-color-emoji but it is not installed
                  Recommends: fonts-ubuntu but it is not installed
                  Recommends: fwupd
                  Recommends: fwupdate
                  Recommends: fwupdate-signed
                  Recommends: gnome-calendar but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gnome-initial-setup but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gnome-software-plugin-snap but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gnome-todo but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gpg-agent
                  Recommends: kerneloops but it is not installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-style-breeze but it is not installed
                  Recommends: network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu but it is not installed
                  Recommends: orca but it is not installed
                  Recommends: packagekit
                  Recommends: printer-driver-brlaser but it is not installed
                  Recommends: printer-driver-m2300w but it is not installed
                  Recommends: snapd but it is not installed
                  Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-report but it is not installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-software but it is not installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-web-launchers but it is not installed
                  Recommends: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**sudo apt-get -f install**
(mostly same error but at the end it's different)

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/ma$
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/re$
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main res$

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/ma$
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/re$
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main res$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
```

**/etc/apt/sources.d**
I didn't see this file in folder /etc/apt but there is:

**sources.list.d** - has some small files inside:

```
boundary.list
boundary.list.distUpgrade
ubuntu-esm-infra-trusty.list
ubuntu-esm-infra-trusty.list.distUpgrade
```

Other info:

**sudo dpkg --configure -a**

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5); however:
  Version of keyboard-configuration on system is 1.178ubuntu2.9.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 237-3ubuntu10.33); however:
  Package systemd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell-extension-appindicator; however:
  Package gnome-shell-extension-appindicator is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock; however:
  Package gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gstreamer1.0-packagekit; however:
  Package gstreamer1.0-packagekit is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on libu2f-udev; however:
  Package libu2f-udev is not installed.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on spice-vdagent; however:
  Package spice-vdagent is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5); however:
  Version of keyboard-configuration on system is 1.178ubuntu2.9.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 locales depends on libc-bin (>> 2.27); however:
  Version of libc-bin on system is 2.23-0ubuntu11.

dpkg: error processing package locales (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-settings-daemon:
 gnome-settings-daemon depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-settings-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.13.91); however:
  Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.16); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-core on system is 0.130ubuntu3.9.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libc-bin:
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.24); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.27-3ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 console-setup
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 gnome-bluetooth
 ubuntu-desktop
 console-setup-linux
 locales
 gnome-settings-daemon
 gnome-control-center
 initramfs-tools
 libc-bin
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` .. Are you using PPA's besides the official repositories ? Pls. add the content of /etc/apt/sources.list to your question too. Also list /etc/apt/sources.d

Comment: Ubuntu server & desktop releases use the *year.month* format, Ubuntu Core intended for IoT appliances uses the *year* format.  Unmet dependencies shouldn't be a problem unless you've introduced third party software sources, in which you'll need to read the messages and look at what the issues are, where they come from etc. It's in the error messages which we cannot read.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I added more details

Answer (score 0):

Credit: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758287

Edit the file: `/usr/bin/apt-show-versions`

Patched the file as shown here:

Replace: `foreach my $arch (keys $href->{$pkg}) {`

With:    `foreach my $arch (keys %{$href->{$pkg}}) {`

Replace: `foreach my $arch ($archname or sort keys $pkgs->{$pkgname}) {`

With:    `foreach my $arch ($archname or sort keys %{$pkgs->{$pkgname}}) {`

Done